# How do you do a command line build of a Xamarin.iOS project?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I've got a working Xamarin.iOS project, using 4.1.9 (on the Alpha channel).

How do I build it from the command line (not from inside Xamarin Studio)?  I tried mdtool and that produced:

```
james@retina:~/svox_workspace/iphone/xamphone$ mono "/Users/james/git/monodevelop/main/build/bin/mdtool.exe" build
INFO [2013-08-21 09:00:03Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Core
MonoDevelop Build Tool
System.DllNotFoundException: libintl.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Catalog:bindtextdomain (intptr,intptr)
  at Mono.Unix.Catalog.Init (System.String package, System.String localedir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.GettextCatalog..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
FATAL ERROR [2013-08-21 09:00:04Z]: System.DllNotFoundException: libintl.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Catalog:gettext (intptr)
  at Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.GettextCatalog.GetString (System.String phrase, System.Object arg0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.SlnFileFormat.ReadFile (System.String fileName, MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildFileFormat format, IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildFileFormat.ReadFile (FilePath file, System.Type expectedType, IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.ReadFile (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String file, System.Type expectedType, MonoDevelop.Projects.FileFormat& format) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.InternalReadWorkspaceItem (System.String file, IProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DefaultProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Autotools.MakefileProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectServiceExtension.LoadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectService.ReadWorkspaceItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String file) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.BuildTool.Run (System.String[] arguments) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.ApplicationService.StartApplication (System.String appId, System.String[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelopProcessHost.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool` or `/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool`.

In other words not directly `mono` on `mdtool.exe` (which might miss configuration...).

Comment: This worked for me: "/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool" build "--configuration:Debug|iPhone"

Comment: Can u please tell me where we type this command? because when I am typing this command on terminal then I am getting error that /Application/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents not exist/not found.

Comment: In the terminal. Note that there's a space in the command (path to Xamarin Studio) that you'll need to escape, e.g. `/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool`. I'll edit my answer.