# How do you force regeneration of *.designer.cs files in a command-line Xamarin build?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm building an iOS Xamarin app from the command line.  The *designer.cs files have been removed.

What command do I run to regenerate the *.designer.cs files?

Answer (score 2):

Encountered in Xamarin Studio 6

Based on [this forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7681/how-to-regenerate-a-view-controllers-designer-cs-file) the *fairly awkward* sequence that worked for me was

- rename the ViewController specified in the storyboard
- save and close the solution
- remove `bin` and `obj` directories
- rebuild

Answer (score 1):

There are actually 3 questions in this topic:

1. If you want to build from command line is explained in this topic: [How do you do a command line build of a Xamarin.iOS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362273/how-do-you-do-a-command-line-build-of-a-xamarin-ios-project)
2. To ignore *.designer.cs you can add a pattern to your .git file called git ignore: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore
3. To regenerate the designer files you can simply rebuild your solution.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that I'm not asking the first two.  And unfortunately, #3 is wrong; there's no mechanism I know about that creates those *designer.cs files at build time.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin Studio 5.8, if you edit the file that originated the designer.cs, save again and rebuild the project it will regenerate the designer.cs

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not true in 5.9.4.

Comment: Another way to go is the creating an empty class and name it with .designer.cs and ensure that contains only the class declaration empty  with the Register ("<CLASS_NAME>") line over declaration.

Then just go to your view and set the Identify>Class Property value with the class inside that .designer.cs