# How to build a Xamarin DLL in visual studio from the command line?

Tags: macos, xamarin, dll, xamarin.ios, devops

Xamarin Studio has been replaced for Visual Studio on MacOS. I have a project that builds a DLL using Xamarin iOS. For DevOps (automated release), I want to build the project for release from the **command line**. I know previously the **mdtool** was used for this purpose, as seen [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362273/how-do-you-do-a-command-line-build-of-a-xamarin-ios-project) but now in visual studio there is no more mdtools binary anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`msbuild` has replaced `mdtool` (and `xbuild`), so all the tasks that once were handled by `mdtool` are now handled by the cross-platform `msbuild` and its standard set of cmd-line options.

### Release configuration:

#### Clean a single project in a solution

```
msbuild /p:SolutionDir=./ /target:Clean /p:Configuration=Release  SomeProjectLibrary/SomeProjectLibrary.csproj
```

#### Build a single project in a solution

```
msbuild /p:SolutionDir=./ /target:Build /p:Configuration=Release SomeProjectLibrary/SomeProjectLibrary.csproj
```

Note: Using Using `SolutionDir=./` so these cmds are being run from the root directory of the solution.

Comment: As an additional info, in my quest for automation, I also found the executable `/Applications/Visual\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/vstool`, I also managed to build with `vstool -v build --target:project_target --configuration:Release project.sln`

Comment: @FelipeCesarAssis In terms of CI, using the Visual Studio Tool Runner (`vstool`) requires that the VS4M is installed, which is not a normal thing to install on macOS CI servers, but yes, it is available and basically it is calling msbuild tasks to perform its work.